# How does youtube load its next video without loading the next page while changing browser history?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When we click on some video on youtube its page does not loads the next page of that particular video but loads the videos on same page using ajax.But how they manupulate browser history too?

Comment: Learn about the HTML5 History API.

Answer (score 1):

and welcome to StackOveflow!

I would suggest you check out the [History Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History)

There you will find methods that allow you to manipulate the history by pushing and replacing states of your browser with javascript.

Hope this helps!